# cant resolve httpclient, httppost, http reponse and NameValuePair

Tags: apache, http-post, httpclient, httpresponse

i know they are no longer available on api-23 but i tried from last 10 hours to add libraries so i can use my previous code but still it doesnt work on my side if someone help me to upgrade my previous code like httpclient to httpURLConnenction

```
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        for (String url : urls) {
            try {

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("btnSubmit", updateTrigger));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total", ""+total));

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                is1 = response.getEntity().getContent();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                error = "ClientProtocolException: " + e.getMessage();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

heres my build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"



defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.androidtraining.practice2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  }

    dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'


}
```

i add these in my build.gradle file like

```
       compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
       compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
      compile 'com.github.jalasoft:HttpClient:1.0.5'
      compile "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1"
```

from above libraris cz.msebera was almost helpul i can remove my all errors by then get a casting error at line

```
         post.setEntity(newUrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
```

so it wasn't helpful too..so thnks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

If continue using the Apache HTTP APIs, you must first declare the following compile-time dependency in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Please read more at the following:

> [Apache HTTP Client Removal](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)

Comment: I can't find it inside your build.gradle file in your question

Comment: For `HttpUrlConnection` sample, pls read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584038/deprecated-methods-how-i-can-replace-it-with-new/33584138#33584138