# How to write http request in javascript?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, httprequest, httpresponse

I know it can be done but i am no good with http request at all. I have a very specific one i need to write. The code is here but i dont know which line to return to my app for the response.

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://v2.api.xapo.com/oauth2/token');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic YTVlMGExMTViYTc1MThjYzphNWUwYTExNWJhNzUxOGNjYTVlMGExMTViYTc1MThjYw==');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = "grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=https://myURI.com";

request.send(body);
```

This is what im trying to do.

```
curl --include --request POST --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --header "Authorization: Basic MYKEYHERE[auth]" --data-binary "grant_type=client_credentials&redirect_uri=MYREDIRECTURI" 'https://v2.api.xapo.com/oauth2/token'
```

The api for this is [here](http://docs.xapo.apiary.io/#reference/oauth2/connecting-to-your-own-resources/obtain-a-token-to-access-your-own-resources)

Comment: I think you can refer to my sample code at the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584038/deprecated-methods-how-i-can-replace-it-with-new/33584138

Comment: This doesnt really help me as i dont understand it. But it does seem to be something like what i need. Do you think you can see if you can work an example for me, or a guide so i understand? @BNK

Comment: IMHO, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html will be good for you to start learning

Comment: Ive checked that out. Its good if you know what the http protocols already do, but i dont. im learning it now but this is little bit of code is my last piece to complete my app which is time sensitive. Thank you for the reference though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see the following code :

```
  function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "demo_get2.asp?fname=Henry&lname=Ford", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
```

**first** you define an instance of `XMLHttpRequest()` that will do the http request for you

**second** the method  `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()`will be listening to state change that means it will be executed once an http responde is returned

**third** `xhttp.open` method will determine your connection config for example here we set a property "POST" then determining the link you want to post to it along with the variables you want to post like this :

1. enter the link
2. put ? mark
3. put the variable name
4. put =
5. put the varible value
6. put & mark and repeat the steps 3 4 5 if you want to post more variable else put nothing .

**fourth** the method `xhttp.send()`will start the http request to the server and once the response is gotten the `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()`will be called then you can get the content of the response with `xhttp.responseText`

I hope this example is clear