# HTTPURLConnection - Outputstream POST to php on webserver

Tags: android

I'm getting mad about HttpUrlConnection an Outputstreams.

I just want to send a string to php and from there put it in a database.

The last two nights I read nearly thousand guides and threads about sending data to webserver, tried almost everything I read - and it's still not working.

```
 protected void phpPOST(final String ServerURL, final String StringToPost)
 {

    Thread newthread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {

            //1. set URL and connect to server
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {

            URL server = new URL(ServerURL + "teilnehmer_update.php");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) server.openConnection();

             //2. set method to POST and enable output
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
             connection.setDoOutput(true);

             //3. open outputstream and send string to url
             OutputStreamWriter outstream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                outstream.write(StringToPost);
                outstream.flush();
                outstream.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("Error!", "ERROR is " + e);}

            finally {if (connection != null) {connection.disconnect();}}
        }
    };
    newthread.start();
}
```

I reduced my php-file to very simple, to secure it's not a php problem. Tried from browser, works fine.

```
<?php
    // for testing, should create an empty file when no no data is recieved.
$file = fopen('test.txt', 'w');
$id   = $_POST['id'];
fwrite($file, $id);
fclose($file);
?>
```

I don't get any errors - so, I don't know what to fix. LogCat is also empty.

I think the Problem is something with the Outputstream (also tried versions BufferdOS,OS,DataOS). As far as I get it, the connection is should open when I create the OS and write to it. - But, in my case it does not do anything...

Any ideas what's wrong with the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Try my code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584038/deprecated-methods-how-i-can-replace-it-with-new/33584138#33584138 to see if it can help

Comment: Yes, it healped. Didn't think about AsyncTask. For my downloadcode I use new Thread - wich works fine. Any Idea why new Thread doesn't work for sending files to server?